# Android notification with buttons click remove notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to make notification with two buttons. I can able to display the notification.

I used setOnClickPendingIntent, once i click on the button i can't able to remove the notification.

I tried `notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;` and  `notificationManager.cancel(id);` its not working. Please guide me what im doing wrong. If i click on the `setContentIntent` its get remove but not in button click.

here the code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatListActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("accept", "true");
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                // Create remote view and set bigContentView.
                RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.notification_message_remote);

                expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_accept, pendingIntent);
                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        //Vibration
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                        //LED
                        .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                        //Ton
                        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("Title"))
                        // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mTitle))
                        .setContentTitle("Notification").build();

                notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
                // hide the notification after its selected
                //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
                notificationManager.cancel(0);
```

Comment: did you try notificationManager.cancelAll();

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your ChatListActivity.onCreate()

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//in this case, it should be 0
manager.cancel(notificationId);
//dismiss notification panel
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```